# Allow users to add / remove settings in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api

I have created a plugin for a client of mine that I think could help a lot of people out there, so I'm in the process of "generalizing" it.

Right now, I'm using the Settings API and textareas in order to accept multiple inputs from the user (one input per row). However, I would like to basically define a single setting (with multiple types of input fields: dropdown lists, text inputs, checkboxes etc) and have an "Add More" button that would allow the user to create as many settings as he/she wants.

Is there any kind of documentation for such things anywhere in Wordpress? I could also read code in order to understand how this can be done, so if someone can give me a plugin that provides this kind of functionality in its settings, it would help a lot.